# jquery javascript switch if else form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, switch-statement

http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDf/1/
[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDf/1/)

Can anybody help please.

The div/form doesn't switsch automaticly in other direction.

thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: If you would like help, please take the time to *clearly* describe the issue you're having. This would include describing the current behavior in contrast to the expected behavior. Also, the link is helpful, but you should really paste the relevant code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue, see http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDf/3/. Be sure to read the capitalized comments! Sorry for yelling, but they're very important.